# zsh warning before executing file

Tags: zsh

I frequently find myself accidentally running python files as shell scripts, e.g. `$ ./test.py`

This has potential to cause lots of damage if there was no shebang line at the start of the file, so I would like a way for zsh to give a warning for doing this.

Does this functionality already exist somewhere?

If not, I'm thinking of using `accept-line` to implement this, but this seems like a catch-all solution, is there a more specific way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use suffix aliases to ensure that `.py` files are run by python:

```
alias -s py='/usr/bin/env python'
```

When you now type command that ends in `.py` on your command line, it will be run with `/usr/bin/env python`.

Note: this does not care whether the file is executable or not. If you want to restrict this to executable `.py` files, you can use a function:

```
runxpy () {
    if [[ -x "$1" ]] ; then
        /usr/bin/env python "$@"
    else
        "$@"
    fi
}
alias -s py=runxpy
```

One restriction is of course that the files in question have to have the `.py` suffix.
Another is that any existing `#!`-line is ignored, but this could be solved by extending `runxpy` to parse the first line instead of just using `/usr/bin/python` every time.